# $f: X \rightarrow Y$ injective, closed. Prove that for $U \in \mathcal{T}_x$ and $M$ ⊆ $Y$, ∃ $V \in \mathcal{T}_y$ s.t $M$⊆$V$ and $f^{-1}(V)$ ⊆ $U$

Tags: general-topology, closed-map

> Let $(X,\mathcal{T}_x), (Y,\mathcal{T}_y)$ be topological spaces and $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be an injective and closed map (i.e. it maps closed sets to closed sets). Let $U$ be an open subset of $X$ and $M$ be a non-empty subset of $Y$ such that $f^{−1}(M) \subset U$. Prove that there exists an open subset $V$ of $Y$ such that $M \subset V$ and $f^{−1}(V) \subset U$

I've made three attempts below (or rather two half-attempts and one real attempt). I've placed exclamation marks on top of equalities or bolded parts where I suspect my logic might be incorrect.

1. My initial idea was that since $f$ is a closed map, it means that $f^{-1}: (Y,\mathcal{T}_y) \rightarrow (X,\mathcal{T}_x)$ is continuous since: $ (f^{-1})^{-1}(W) = f(W)$ is closed in $\mathcal{T}_y$ **for every $W$ closed** in $\mathcal{T}_x$. But this would then imply that $f(U)$ is open in $\mathcal{T}_y$ for every $U$ open in $\mathcal{T}_x$ (since $f^{-1}$ is continuous), and this cannot be true, otherwise an open map would be equivalent to a closed map, which is not true from what I know.
2. If it somehow instead turned out that $f$ is continuous instead, then maybe one could do the proof by: $U \subseteq \mathcal{T}_x \iff \exists V \subseteq \mathcal{T}_y$  s.t  $f^{-1}(V) = U$. Since $f^{-1}(M) \subseteq U$ and $f^{-1}(V) = U \Rightarrow M \subseteq V, f^{-1}(V) \subseteq U$ and $V$ open.
3. $U$ open in $\mathcal{T}_x \Rightarrow X \setminus U$ closed in $\mathcal{T}_x \Rightarrow f(X \setminus U)$ closed in $\mathcal{T}_y$. But $f(X \setminus U) = f(X) \setminus f(U) \overset{!}{=} Y \setminus f(U)$ open in $\mathcal{T}_y \Rightarrow f(U)$ open in $\mathcal{T}_y$. $f(U)$ is our desired $V$ since: $f^{-1}(V) = f^{-1}(f(U)) = U$ (hence $f^{-1}(f(U)) \subseteq U$), $M \subseteq V = f(U)$

My questions are:

1. In attempt 1, I've assumed that $f^{-1}(W)$ exists for every $W \in \mathcal{T}_y$, which can only be the case for surjective $f$. Is this where my contradiction is arising from?
2. Am I on the right track in my second attempt, if so how do I show $f$ is continuous? However, it seems a bit odd that I'm getting $f^{-1}(V) = U$ instead of $f^{-1}(V) \subseteq U$.
3. What about attempt 3? Again here I've assumed that $f$ is surjective since I set $f(X) = Y$.
4. If none of these attempts are on the right path, could you give me a hint?

Comment: Your are on the right track with your third attempt, but there is no reason nor need to assume $f$ to be surjective. Since $U$ is open, $X-U$ is closed and so is $f(X-U)$, as $f$ is closed. Now $Y-f(X-U)$ is a nice open set of $Y$. Try to show that $Y-f(X-U)$ satisfies the properties you want.

Comment: Also note there are maps $f$ which are closed and injective, but neither open nor continuous. E.g., take $[0,1]$ with the indiscrete topology, and let $f$ the inclusion into $\mathbb R$ with the usual topology.

Comment: @carciofo21 Thank you for your answer. Continuing on what you said. $V = Y \setminus  f(X \setminus U)$. $V$ is open. $$f^{-1}(V) = f^{-1}(Y) \setminus (X \setminus U) \overset{!}{=} (f^{-1}(Y) \setminus X) \cup (f^{-1}(Y) \cap U) = \varnothing \cup (f^{-1}(Y) \cap U) \subseteq U$$. $$V = Y \setminus  f(X \setminus U) = Y \setminus  ((f(X) \setminus f(U)) \supseteq Y \setminus  (f(X) \setminus M) \supseteq M$$  Correct?

Comment: @jacob That is insightful, thank you!

Comment: Yes, but, more easily notice that $f^{-1}(Y)=X$.